# How can I extract values from a list of tuples inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
d={'Test':'Math','results':[{'name':'Paul','score':78},{'name':'Ann','score':87},{'name':'John','score':82}]}
```

I have this dictionary with a list inside. I would like to sum the score: 78+87+82. I've tried some approaches, but I failed. Help me, please!
PS.: I use Python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dct = {'Test':'Math','results':[{'name':'Paul','score':78},{'name':'Ann','score':87},{'name':'John','score':82}]}

print(sum(d["score"] for d in dct["results"]))
```

`dct["results"]` is the list of dicts i.e:

```
[{'name':'Paul','score':78},{'name':'Ann','score':87},{'name':'John','score':82}], `
```

`d["score"] for d` accesses the in each dict using the `score` key in that list and we just `sum` all those values we extract.

Comment: Fantastic! I am impressed how easy is your solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've got this solution:

```python
def sumScores(d):
    score=0
    for element in d['results']:
        score += element['score']
    return score
```

Tip: I see that your question is voted down, it's because that's a simple problem that you CAN solve yourself. Try to solve it B4 asking 4 help.